# How to show that $2^{\sqrt{n}} = n^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log_2 n}}$?

Tags: logarithms

How to show that $2^{\sqrt{n}} = n^{\tfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log_2 n}}$?

Well, I've no idea how to begin solving it, and I'm struggling every day with these questions about logairthms in my course, can anyone give me a hint how to handle these kind of questions?

Comment: They are not equal.

Comment: @SomuSaiteja Actually I solved it correctly. It is $n^{logloglogn}$..

Comment: @SomuSaiteja I've mistaken with $2^{\sqrt{n}}$. Can you help me with that?

Comment: When you make a serious error entering a question you should probably delete it and ask again correctly. Just editing it makes the existing correct answers to the old question meaningless or wrong.

Comment: Hint: Show $2=n^{\frac{1}{\log_2{n}}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to the original question

> Prove that $(\log\log n)^{\log n} = n^{\tfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}}$

Take the logarithm of the right-hand side:
$$
\log\bigl(n^{\tfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}}\bigr)=
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}\log n=\sqrt{n}
$$
so the right-hand side is $e^{\sqrt{n}}$ which is much greater, for large $n$, than the left-hand side.

### Answer to the modified question

> Prove that $2^{\sqrt{n}} = n^{\tfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}}$

If $\log$ denotes the logarithm in base $a$, the same argument as before shows
$$
n^{\tfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}}=a^{\sqrt{n}}
$$
If your base is $2$, then you get $2^{\sqrt{n}}$. However, writing $\log n$ to denote the logarithm in base $2$ is, at least, not standard.

Comment: I've edit my question, I had a mistake, it is $2^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS You should check your questions before pushing them. However, the relation is wrong unless you specify that with “log” you mean the logarithm in base two, which is at least non standard notation.

Comment: I meant to base 2, sorry that I didn't note it. I've solved the equation $n^x = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$ and got to $x = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{logn}$

Answer (score 1):

Not equal.

Take $n=e$.

Then

$$(\log \log e)^{\log e}=0^1=0$$

and

$$e^{\frac{\sqrt e}{\log e}}=e^{\sqrt e}\ne 0.$$

Comment: I've edit my question, I had a mistake, it is $2^{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^b=c^{b\log_c(a)}$ then it follows that
$$n^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}}=2^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log_2 n}\cdot\log_2 n}=2^{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: I've edit my question, I had a mistake, it is $2^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I meant to base 2, sorry that I didn't note it. I've solved the equation $n^x = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$ and got to $x = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{logn}$